# S3 QuickTime Vid loaded w/ exp URL in 3 months not cached. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, quicktime

I am using the ruby gem AWS::S3 to generate expiring urls for my assets on S3, some of them are quicktime movies of size. I would prefer them not repeatedly downloaded each time requested to the client's browser. Since they are protected and whose access is done in authenticated urls, I set the expiration usually in 3 months, so I thought at least they only have to redownload them every three months, which is not too bad. But it didn't work. by didn't work I mean I use the quicktime object script provided by apple and with cache='true' enabled. It works for videos on garden variety webhosts, as I have tested. so i am pretty sure I have run out of options to look into on Quicktime's end.

What do you suggest?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investigate the Cache-control headers that you get from S3. You can use e.g. Firebug to do this.

Comment: Hey Chris, sorry to have taken so long to reply to your answer, thank you by the way. I was away for the past week.